# Python, PyQt4, Qt Designer: Select and process text entered in a PyQt4 text editor field

Tags: python, pyqt4, qt-designer

I am experimenting with a small editor created in Python with a PyQt4 GUI.

So far, the program can open a text file, display the text, save changes to it or perform an action on it entirely (like pressing a button and count the words).

But, I want to create a function that changes a selected text (in the textEdit object of PyQt4). For example, select a passage and count the numbers of words, or invert the letter, or whatever).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

textCursor gives you the cursor, it's a QTextCursor.

It has a slot called select, that you can use. Anyway look at that class, you will find what you need.

http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qtextcursor.html

http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qtextedit.html